# Generic change tracking class improvements

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, webforms

I am developing a generic reflection class for change tracking.  What I have works just fine for all classes that I put it through.  I am getting ready to move it out as part of a tool to the entire group.  I am interested in improving this a bit more before I role it out to everyone.  It is called from methods that have error handling in place so that part is not an issue.  Also this works perfectly in our logic the way we flatten objects for change tracking, but am I missing something that could be an issue even though it works perfectly for the usual situations.

```
public class ChangeTracker
{
    public static string GetChangesString<T,S>(T original, T current, S dto, string[] exluded)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        PropertyInfo[] names = typeof(S).GetProperties();


        string displayName = string.Empty;
        foreach (PropertyInfo item in names)
        {

            if (exluded.Contains(item.Name)) continue;

            //method that sets display name to either the property name or the display attribute if present
            displayName = GetDisplayName(item);

            object propA = original.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(original, null);
            object propB = current.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(original, null);

            if (propA == null && propB == null) continue;

            if (propA == null && propB != null)
            {
                //appendline for value added
            }
            else if (propB == null && propA != null)
            {
                //appendline for value removed
            }
            else if (propA.ToString() != propB.ToString())
            {
                //appendline for value changed
            }



        }

        return sb.ToString();



    }

    private static string GetDisplayName(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        string display = string.Empty;
        //Check for displayattribute and set correct name
        return display;
    }
}
```

Specifically this is my question.

Is there a better way I can do the propA and propB setting to improve performance?  It works on one object changing and I have tested it up to 103 properties with no performance issues, but I try to avoid stuff like this when I can.

Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Granted point 4 might belong on codereview, but the reason for this question is really point 1 and 2 which are appropriately directed to SO.  I don't know how to add the .Where to remove the if statement because it doesn't work with everything I have tried.

Comment: `typeof(S).GetProperties().Where(p => !excluded.Contains(p.Name))` ;) - you should really ask one question per question, though (on the appropriate sites), otherwise you get into a situation where you have lots of partial answers. How do you accept the correct answer when you have 4 different answers answering 4 different questions?

Comment: @Ant P, you are correct that was probably a bad choice of laziness on my behalf.

Comment: @AntP, I have added a question specifically that asks the part that you answered and modified this one to only include the questions answered by Guru, because you deserve credit for you answer and it might be easier for others to find broken down.  Here is a link to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387877/where-to-exclude-properties-in-reflection) and I will mark you as the answer if you want to put your suggestion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection + [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) combination to build getter `Func`'s. And I recommned to build this expressions on application start and cache them(per type), that should drastically improve performance. But this will greatly increase you code base size=)

Comment: I will look at Expression Trees.  I don't think that will work on some of our older servers, but I have not researched enough to say for sure.  We will not be permitted to build this on application start for sure and cache it.  Sometimes performance goes to the wayside because of perceived security risks.

Comment: Actually thank you for your comment.  I don't think my array.Contains is going to work on our older servers either.

Comment: I am currently developing on 4.5.  Some of our developers are still on 3.5.

Comment: Expression Trees are available since 3.5 as I know, so you should be fine) Also i wanted to mention that your way of using `ToString` to compare props will require all user defined classes, which can be used like props, to have correctly overriden `ToString` otherwise you change tracker would not work, but using expressions you have options to create you own comparer which will drill down the class or use `Expression.Equal` to call uquality operator.

Comment: I thought expression trees were 4.0 and above.  We do have a comparer generic class that we can use, but in reality every change we monitor boils down to string, int, bool, and datetime.  There is an issue between VB and C# on default datetimes that had to be overcome, but that was trivial.  From what I have looked at though I think you are correct and that Expression Trees are the direction I need to go.  Thanks