# .Where to exclude properties in reflection

Tags: linq

I have the following code as well as a `string[]` called excluded.  I want to grab all of the properties of any class, except the ones specifically called out in excluded.

Is there a `.Where` that will allow my `Propertyinfo[]` to not contain the excluded properties?

```
PropertyInfo[] names = typeof(S).GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
typeof(S).GetProperties().Where(p => !excluded.Contains(p.Name)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do the job:

```
PropertyInfo[] names = typeof(S).GetProperties().Where(c => !excluded.Contains(c.Name)).ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  AntP had actually answered this as part of another question that I could not accept the answer for so I accepted that answer since it was actually first.